# Error with Folium iframe and Flask

Tags: python, flask, routes, folium

I've experimented quite a bit / searched through solutions here on the site, but so far am having trouble displaying a folium map within an iframe when the holding page is served from Flask.

```
wiki
    app
        __init.py__           
        routes.py
    static
        map_test.html
    templates
        map.html
```

Basic overview: on **map.html**, I have an iframe where I am trying to source the **map_test.html** file, a sample Folium map.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what to rearrange or fix? My thinking is the static folder, the map.html, and map_test.html files are all in the right location, but my routing is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Here are the various code bits.

> **init.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
```

> **routes.py**

```
@app.route('/map/')
def map():
    map = folium.Map(
        location = [37.852995, -120.999986],
        tiles = 'Stamen Terrain',
        detect_retina = True, 
        prefer_canvas = True,
        zoom_start = 4
    )

    startLat_1 = 34.286565
    startLong_1 = -118.561021
    clusterData_1 = [retLatLong(startLat_1, startLong_1) for i in range(100)]
    plugins.FastMarkerCluster(clusterData_1).add_to(map)

    map_path = app.root_path + '/' + 'static/map_test.html'
    map.save(map_path)

    return render_template('map.html')

@app.route('/static/map_test.html')
def map_data():
    return send_file(url_for('static', filename = 'map_test.html'))
```

> **map.html**

```
<div>
<iframe src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'map_test.html')}}" height="600" width="800">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Through the code above, I'm able to successfully generate **map_test.html** in the static folder, but cannot figure how/why to route it properly into the iframe.

The error from the current code configuration above is:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/map_test.html'
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2018 13:01:50] "GET /static/map_test.html HTTP 1.1" 500